# how to solve Open File Dialog hangs, Waiting for Localhost

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I am working on the project. In my System when I run the project it is running nicely, but after uploading it to my domain when I check, OpenFileDialog hangs, Waiting for Localhost in my web application the user has to choose a location to save his file using open file dialog after publishing it to IIS i and I face this problem that's waiting for localhost. so what should I do to make the user choose the location to save his file?

```
   Protected Sub FnOpenFileDialog()
        changedpath = 1
        If changedpath = 1 Then
            Dim openfile As New SaveFileDialog
            openfile.InitializeLifetimeService()


            Dim projectName As String = txtProjectName.Value
            openfile.FileName = projectName
            If openfile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

                Dim pathDestination As String = Path.GetFullPath(openfile.FileName)

                If Not Directory.Exists(pathDestination) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathDestination)
                End If
                newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathDestination, "Temp")

                If Not Directory.Exists(newPath) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath)
                End If
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim sourcepath As String = "C:\Users\O6\Desktop\SW001-LEVEL 1 Base Case-REV.45.hsc"
            DestPath = NewScenarioProfilePage.newPath & "\"
            CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestPath)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not solvable, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You have to show no dialog like that.

Comment: The web server does not have access to the client's file system. You can instead make it a download, and the web browser will present a save dialog to the user.

Comment: You come to my site to view a cat picture. And then I run code to look on your computer for banking information, accounting information. heck search/grab a Excel file or text file called passwords, and open that file and steal all your information. So browsers code is locked down. You free to run ANY code on the computer running the web site for files, but such code does not know or run on the users desktop - it would be too high of  security risk. If you need a users file - they have to up-load the file and they will be 100% aware of this action. Client side files are 100% off limits to code.

Comment: and save goes for any file location - maybe they are using a android phone - what is the file locations now? you don't even know what kind of file system - they might be using  iPad. So, you can allow them to download a file - but only THEY can choose where to save - not you. And if you need a user's file, then they have to up-load the file, and then your code behind is plane jane vb code - but that only applies to where you want save/use the file on the web hosting computer (which during development is your desktop computer). So code behind is local web server file system - not client side.